# грокаем алгоритмы . глава 8. add

Tags: python, множества

пример из главы 8. Жадные алгоритмы. Суть - перебирает все множества. находит пересечение.
Не могу понять как работает final_station.add (best_station) ? при запуске интерпретатора всегда разный ответ. Если вместо add пишу append и убираю set. все ок.

```
states_needed=set(["mt","wa","or","id","nv","ut","ca","az"])
stations ={}
stations["kone"]=set(["id","nv","ut"])
stations["ktwo"]=set(["id","wa","mt"])
stations["kthree"]=set(["or","nv","ca"])
stations["kfour"]=set(["nv","ut"])
stations["kfive"]=set(["ca","az"])
final_station=set()
while states_needed: 
    best_station=None
    state_covered=set()
    for station,state in stations.items():
        covered=states_needed & state 
        if len(covered)>len(state_covered):
            best_station=station
            state_covered=covered
    final_station.add (best_station) 
    states_needed-=state_covered

print( final_station)
```

Answer (score 1):

Множество - неупорядоченный объект. В связи с этим порядок элементов рандомный. В отличии от списка где соблюдается порядок.

Comment: я, правильно понял, что операция add добавляет элемент в множество, где все эти элементы находятся в рандомном порядке. потому принт их печатает всегда по-разному?

Comment: Изначально выбрав для хранения множество, вы для себя должны понимать, что при вызове порядок элементов будет рандомным. И еще, множество не имеет метода `append()`, а список не имеет метода `add()`

Comment: @Alex, да правильно понял. Однако есть  еще и упорядоченные словари если они очень нужны. `import collections` и определяем словарь так: `d = collections.OrderedDict()`.
Тогда все всегда будет по порядочку )
.
Кроме того можно использовать Index  из модуля Pandas... Он тоже ведет себя как упорядоченній словарь..